# jQuery Mobile and Scrollview automatically enables scrolling on content divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I'm using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Scrollview](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/). This has been the perfect solution for me so far as I had some bad experiences with the scrolling functions in jQuery Mobile, and again with a plugin called iScroll.

My only problem is that now all the `div` tags that have `data-role="content"` automatically has scrolling enabled, which is causing some final problems where some touch events aren't firing because the touch must be caught as a scroll.

These errors only occur on two content pages, both of which don't even require scrolling. I it enables scrolling on all content by design, but is there a way to disable scrolling for certain `div` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a long time trying all sorts of things, but the general idea was that I wanted a class I could use to stop the scrolling on that content div (`noscroll`).

Overriding the `addClass` method to prevent adding the `ui-scrollview-view` class caused a lot of errors elsewhere. I have no idea why, possibly another plugin on the page is trying to override it again?

Eventually I had to manually change `scrollview.js`, which as it happens is only a small file. On line 19, there's a selector to select all elements where `data-role` is `content`. After this selector, I added `.not('.noscroll')`.

Quick change, and I made sure I noted everywhere I could that I had changed this file from the original. But after 5 hours trying to find a better solution, I settled for it!

Answer (score 1):

I dig out the source and i've found a workaround. The plugin filters out the div's with the class "ui-scrollview-clip".
HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could solve it using this solution (thx [Dessus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074514/dessus)):

I think you might find that the event is consumed in the scrollview control. You can override the javascript handler against that control to allow it to keep bubbling.

To override the function you can use this technique: Overriding a JavaScript function while referencing the original

Having a quick look at the file, it looks like this method could hold clues as to what you want:

_handleDragMove: function(e, ex, ey)

specifically:

var svdir = this.options.direction; if (!this._directionLock)

I was using the version of scrollview shown here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-nested.html

Comment: I tried this for the addClass function but it broke some of the addClass calls and I could never work it out. I did fix it in the end, I'll post the solution when I get to a PC (on phone atm)

Answer (score -1):

Try inverting the scroll direction. If you have an horizontal scrollView, do:

```
$('#yourid').scrollview({ direction: 'y' });
```

And 'x' for a vertical scrollView.
Change back the direction to enable the scroll again.

Comment: How does this disable scrolling?